# How to migrate all AWS services (including running instance, API, Snapsorts) to its sub account with consolidate Billing?

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, migration

I have one master AWS account and have linked one subaccount with it. I want to migrate all AWS services (including running instance, API, Snapsorts, user group permissions, tags, etc) to subaccount with consolidated billing.

How can I achieve this?

Does Cloudformation help to move all resources including data (files, configuration, database tables) to replicate same setup to other account?

Comment: This *might* be a better fit for [webapps.se].

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you aren't going to be able to move like you want. What you're trying to do is migrate your all your resources to an entirely new account and that neither simple (see below) nor is it actually possible to do directly.
The best practice is to template your infrastructure (that's what CloudFormation does and OpsWorks can help manage the running of that infrastructure - there are other tools, though...check out Hashicorp), version control your application and db code, build a code deployment pipeline (I use a combo of Jenkins and CodeDeploy), get your data into a backup system (S3 is a great choice) so that you can move it between accounts, and then build, test, break, rinse, and repeat.
Let me reiterate: this is not easy. I've just summarized what three people have been doing for three months solid and we are still only 2 stacks into a 5 stack deployment pipeline.
Can you give us more detail on why you are trying to move to a sub-account? Would it be possible to start a new account, and make the one you are currently working in the sub-account?

Comment: Actually we have all websites in one aws account but one of site has been grew much and so we need to migrate that site related instances and resources to new account which will be handled by different team. As of now, we are thinking to migrate VPC, Subnets, Security roles, groups etc using Cloudformation and we will migrate EC2, RDS, S3 manually by sharing AMI/Snapshots to new account.

Answer (score 0):

I have one approach on how you can achieve this but this approach is yet to implement.

1. Create Cloud formation template from existing server of source account.
2. Modify template and add ECS and Docker related changes to template along with this also pass environment /data variables for different environments (qa, dev etc.) to make it reusable.
3. Import this modified template to destination account using cloud formation.
4. For S3. 
   a) Get destination account id. 
   b) In source account, create a bucket policy which allows access to Destination (or New) account. 
   c) Attach group policy and valid iam user of that group to destination account. 
   d) Once destination account has access to s3 buckets, we can copy buckets using command line interface aws cli. aws s3 sync s3://sourcebucket s3://destinationbucket
5. For RDS.
   a) Create a snapshot of the database. 
   b) Share the snapshot with the target account. 
   c) In the target account, create a DB instance from the snapshot
6. You can manually create groups, users and roles in new account with policy similar to current source account or you can use Cloud Formation tool for roles and groups.
7. You can use Cloud Formation tool for network setup in new account.
   a) Create json template including security groups, roles, vpc, subnets from existing source account.
   b) Import this json template in new account using Cloud Formation Tool.

See if this helps.